# cn1 - replace background image

Tags: css, background-image, codenameone

I have a button on which I set the background image using css, and then sometimes need to change it dynamically in the code.  But if I change it, I see both images, one on top of the other.
[image]

Here's my css:

```
ExpertVideoButton{
    cn1-derive: Label;
    background-image: url(images/play-video.png);
    cn1-source-dpi: 180;
    cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fit;
}
```

And my code:

```
mStateMachine.findViewVideoBtn(f).getAllStyles().setBgImage(mStateMachine.res.getImage("no_video.png"));
```

The previous background image doesn't get replaced by the new one.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Update**

The original background image wasn't actually being set from the css - there was a css style that was unused, and the image was being set from the code, twice. The first time I had made it the `Label`'s icon, and the second time its background image.  Unfortunately, this was a case of me having trouble reading my own code!

Comment: I would consider down-voting this if that were possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use transparent images you need to set the bgTransparency of the style to transparent (0) in the CSS (not sure how you do it there).